# The Scrollbar's ScrollController has no ScrollPosition attached while using for loop in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a for loop to display some text with a scrollbar. It started throwing me this error - `The Scrollbar's ScrollController has no ScrollPosition attached.`

When I was not using for lopp, i.e., when I was directly just copy pasted `row` and `sizedbox` several time as children of `listview`, I didn't got the error.

Here is the code -

```
List<String> list1 = [
    "Academic Year",
    "Lead Id",
    "Lead created date",
    "Student name",
    "Grade",
    "Date of birth",
    "Gender",
    "Email id",
    "Address",
    "Counsellor",
    "BDA",
    "Digital Counsellor"
  ];

  List<String> list2 = [
    "2023",
    "156388",
    "22-03-2019",
    "Ankit",
    "9th",
    "21-04-2008",
    "Male",
    "ankit@gmail.com",
    "None",
    "2023",
    "156388",
    "22-03-2019"
  ];

.............

Container(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.5,
   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
         vertical: getProportionateScreenWidth(32),
    ),
    child: Scrollbar(
        controller: controller,
        isAlwaysShown: true,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
               horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(24),
            ),
            child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    for(int i=0;i<list1.length;i++)
                        Column(
                           children: [
                              Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      list1[i],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: primaryText,
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      list2[i],
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87,
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Listview.builder` to build a list of items for you, instead of for loop.

Here's the code

```
Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.5,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: getProportionateScreenWidth(32),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(24),
          ),
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: list1.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {  
         return
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          list1[index],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: primaryText,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          list2[index],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black87,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    
                  ],
                );
            }
            
          ),
        ),
      )
```

You may assign `controller` to `Listview.builder` , if you want to scroll it programmatically.